# IllegalArgumentException: property PublicID is not on root type entity.UserRegion

Tags: sql, guidewire, gosu

I'm querying a join entity, userregion, to find regions with a particular zipcode and users that are active. Then I compare the results between the two of them.

```
userregion
------------------------
PublicID | UserID | RegionID

regionzone
------------------------
Code | ZoneType | Region(FK)

user
------------------------
Credential | Region (FK)
```

```
var regQuery = Query.make(UserRegion).join("Region").join("ID", RegionZone, "Region").compare("Code", Equals, polZip)
var userQuery = Query.make(UserRegion).join("User").join("Credential").compare("Active", Equals, true)
regQuery.subselect("PublicID", CompareIn, userQuery, "Credential.PublicID")
```

The subselect is returning the following error: IllegalArgumentException: property PublicID is not on root type entity.UserRegion

I'm not quite sure what the issue is here, so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the subselect query, Can you remove the double quotes in "Credential.PublicID" and try to execute the query again.